# Winword.exe processes will not close on server

Tags: c#, office-interop

Good day all
I have a bit of a head scratcher on my hands.
The following code runs on my server and it does work for what it is intended.

```
public void RenderWithData(string strcaseno, string strdocpath, string strdocsp, string stramnt)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application[];
    string suffix = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    string sourceFileName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strdocpath);
    string destFileName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Cache/" + ActiveLogin.Login + Session.SessionID.ToString + suffix + ".doc");
    Word.Document docDepetal = new Word.Document();
    FileInfo objFileInfo = default(FileInfo);


try {
    File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName);

    SqlSingleQuery cmd = new SqlSingleQuery(strdocsp);
    cmd.AddInt("@USERID", ActiveLogin.UserID);
    string ParameterName = "value0";
    cmd.AddVarChar(ParameterName, 50, strcaseno);
    cmd.AddMoney("@NEWCONSENT", stramnt);
    cmd.Execute();

    docDepetal = appWord.Documents.Open(destFileName);

    Word.Bookmarks MyBookMarks = docDepetal.Bookmarks();


    foreach (string bookmark in cmd.Columns.Keys) {
        MyBookMarks.Item(bookmark).Range.Text = cmd.Columns.Item(bookmark).ToString();
    }


    docDepetal.Protect(Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyComments, false, "password");
    docDepetal.Save();
    docDepetal.Close();
    appWord.Quit();
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(appWord);
    appWord = null;
    objFileInfo = new FileInfo(destFileName);
    DisplayDownloadDialog(objFileInfo);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ShowErrorMsg(ex.Message);
} finally {
    if (appWord != null) {
        if (docDepetal != null) {
            docDepetal.Close();
        }
        appWord.Quit();
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(appWord);
    }

    if (File.Exists(destFileName)) {
        File.Delete(destFileName);
    }
}
```

}

Now my problem is every once in a while the winword.exe process will not close on the server, the every other winword.exe process that opens after that will not close either. This then results in a "creating an instance of the com component with clsid {00020906-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} from the iclassfactory failed due to the following error: 8001010a." error that is displayed each time a new request is sent to create a document.

I would like to know if there is something I can do differently in this code that would resolve this issue.

Please keep in mind that the documents being created are templates that are populated at run time and do not require any interactivity on the server.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: I've had similar issues before with running Excel on a server as well. If I remember correctly, you should explicitly close ALL objects that you opened in the application. In your case, you might have to explicitly close and dispose off EACH Bookmark object, then the Bookmarks object, then the document, then Word itself. However, I also remember this technique not working for me then, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Running Office programs on a server is a very bad practice.  You can fix the problem you have now by forcing a garbage collection with GC.Collect().  What you can't easily fix is having too many clients connected to the server, each creating their own WinWord.exe instance.  Too many is a very low number, WinWord is a very heavy process that was designed to run on a workstation only.

Comment: There is an interresting workaround and a pointer about "resiliency" here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749640/close-ms-office-c-sharp-console

Answer (score 2):

This is more than likely because you have unclosed COM objects that were created.

I can see for instance that:

```
MyBookMarks.Item(bookmark).Range.Text = cmd.Columns.Item(bookmark).ToString();
```

Creates a number of COM objects which are not closed. Because they are still alive, the winword.exe process will stay alive due to them.

In order to ensure that each COM object is closed, you must do this on each COM object created:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(bookMark);
```

For instance:

```
// declare below variables...

try
{
    bookMark = MyBookMarks.Item(bookmark);

    columns = cmd.Columns;
    item = columns.Item(bookmark);

    range = bookMark.Range;
    range.Text = item.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // ...
}
finally
{
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(bookMark);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(columns);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);

    bookMark = null;
    columns = null;
    item = null;
    range = null;

    // A good idea depending on who you talk to...
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

Comment: GC.Collect(); would normally be the way to go - but on a Server?

Comment: @ChristianSauer 'depending on who you talk to'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that: Word on the server is not supported and is almost never a good idea. Microsoft strongly discourages such "solutions".
If you have to read / write word documents I would recommend using a third party Library or mirosoft open xml. This is way more stable, secure and magnitudes faster (factor 100 for me).

If you absolutely want to use word: Implement a "watcher" thread which checks if the word process has really stopped, and if not does a hardkill on the process. This is an extremely ugly solution, but is the only way to force word closed - there are bugs within word, which prevent word vom closing properly once in a while.

Comment: Chances are the process is still alive due to objects that have not been destroyed by the calling code. Ensuring the object have been destroyed is the best place to start.

Comment: -1/+1 Your analysis of why Word is left open, and statement that "Word on the server is not supported" are both pretty much incorrect. However, I agree with your advice to use a library designed for producing Office documents instead of using Office COM Interop.  Personally, I would prefer to see the latter expressed as a comment instead.

Comment: What's not supported is automation of Office in a service since they run in session 0. But yes, COM is a weak solution here. As Jonathon says, that should be a comment.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Word on the server IS not supported. Read this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757. If you read this article, it is clear that Microsoft thinks that Office is a very bad idea on the server.
So, yes you can use it. Does anyone think that is a good idea? No. So just say "not recommended" or "not supported".

Comment: @rhughes Yes, I think so. But it is incredibly difficult to track down those objects. For instance, it could be an intermediate object because you are acessing something like "Apllication.Presentation.Object". Office spews tons of objects and even in a stand alone application it is very difficult to track them down. Normally you could call "Gc.collect" twice, but on a server that is a no-go.
Also: there are rare instances when word just hangs - so you HAVE to  think about that problem anyway.

Comment: +1. I read this article in the past and I knew MS does not recommend this. Despite this, it's working as some quick and dirty solution that requires attention and monitoring.

Comment: If you are calling `Apllication.Presentation.Object`, then the problem stems from there. One of the joys of COM is you should never 'double dot' as the expression goes. Split the statements up and release them accordingly. But yes, it is a pain.